# very simple video player on jPanel java netbeans

Tags: java, swing, video, netbeans

i have googled and tried many things but could not get to work.
please help.
i have a file located in C:/a.mpg
i don't need to play every format.if playing flv is easier, i can convert my videos to flv and put it there.
i have a j panel on j Frame only to play the video.( no need any controllers etc..) 
when i open the app i just need to play the video C://a.mpg on J panel.
its a Que managment software and i want to play a Advertisement on the monitor.(J Panel)

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage)    {
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
final File f = new File(workingDir, "/media/b.flv");
System.out.println(f);
final Media m = new Media(f.toURI().toString());
final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(m);
final MediaView mv = new MediaView(mp);
final DoubleProperty width = mv.fitWidthProperty();
final DoubleProperty height = mv.fitHeightProperty();

width.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "width"));
height.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "height"));
 mv.setPreserveRatio(true);

StackPane root = new StackPane();
root.getChildren().add(mv);

final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 960, 540);
scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);

primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.setTitle("Full Screen Video Player");
 primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
primaryStage.show();
mp.play();
}
```

thank you..

Comment: *".. but could not get to work."* What did you expect to happen? What actually happened? For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). BTW - given this new window is solely for displaying a video, I'd recommend going 'complete Java-FX' rather than trying to mix Swing and Java-FX.

Comment: Almost forgot.. Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!